# MVC2: Using ScaffoldColumn(false) but still display the property on DisplayForModel()

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

Let's say I hav this model:

```
public class PartyGorilla
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gorilla's Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Everything works as desired when using EditorForModel() in my edit/create views but if I use DisplayForModel() in my details view the Id property is not being shown, which is not what I want. My question is: is there another attribute I need to ad or do I need to cook up a custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add the `LabelFor` `DisplayFor` the `id` column before the `DisplayForModel`.  I don't really see a simpler solution to that problem.

You could also make a separate ViewModel, but that has a nasty non-dry footprint for what it actually accomplishes:

```
public class PartyGorillaView
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gorilla's Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class PartyGorillaEdit
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gorilla's Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you think about, given the specific nature of a ViewModel it wouldn't hurt so bad to have a display specific ViewModel ... having it inherit from the first one and overriding the Id property wouldn't be such an ugly solution. Thanks for the tip. Also, Editable (false) doesn't seem to do much in MVC :s

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [HiddenInput] attribute. You can choose to display the value but it's not editable:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

or do not display the value at all:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: A good solution too, but the field is going to be there hidden in the form which is what I dont want.

Comment: If you specify DisplayValue=true in the first example above, then the value will be shown and not hidden. You have your choice either way.